# Why are disc wheels not used in the front on professional track sprint races?

Tags: track-racing, disc-wheel

Why are they used only in the back if there is no risk of winds at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sprint often requires quick direction changes. With a quick turn of the wheel a disc becomes a rudder in the wind and can behave unexpectedly. Even in TT, many riders will elect something other than a disc in the front simply because front discs are a little more skittery. A disc in match sprint c/would be dangerous. The UCI recognizes this and only allows rear disc in match sprint.

Comment: Great first answer, but you're assuming that the reader is reading your answer after Alex's.  You should edit your answer to stand alone better.

Answer (score 9):

Because it's not permitted under UCI regulations.

Rule 1.3.018 applies, which includes this section:

> In track competition, including motor-pacing, the use of a front disc wheel is only permitted in the specialities against the clock.

Disc wheels are commonly used in the sprint qualifying round (i.e. the flying 200 metre TT).

---

The natural follow-on question is :
*Why do UCI regulations allow rear disc wheels, but not front disc wheels?*

I can't answer for the UCI technical commission but to guess it's because the handling characteristics of a front disc wheel makes them less suitable for rapid response to steering input, a trait desirable in mass start and match racing (ie, it's a safety consideration). Using a disc on the rear doesn't affect steering response. The difference (slowness) in steering response of a front disc was my experience when using them on the track. Apart from individual timed events I used them during team pursuits.

As to there being no wind, while that's true in an absolute sense, it doesn't mean a bike and rider experiences zero yaw at the track. You experience wind yaw when in the turns, and when entering a turn a rider experiences a change in yaw angle which also contributes to handling issues with a front disc. On average the yaw experienced on the track is a few degrees. Timed events are ridden under controlled and predictable conditions with inherently less risk than match and mass start races.